# iOS Swift - QR Code

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I need to implement the feature such as that available in Blackberry Messenger, i.e. user can add another user by scanning their QR code.

I found libraries out there that can help generate QR codes and also threads here to help with that. What I am unable to conceptualize is this: When a friend comes to scan my QR code, how can the application recognize that this QR code scanned is related to that person in the service database? I read that QR codes hold information up to 1800 characters or so. My question is, when I scan the QR code, will i get the stream of information from the scanner or does it work in some other way?

Thanks for helping out in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CIDetector](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CIDetector) which will give you [CIQRCodeFeature](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CIQRCodeFeature/index.html) objects, containing the message as a string.